# Is it possible to hide a div when depending on its inner content?

Tags: css

Is it possible to hide an element depending on its inner content ?

ex:

```
<div class="score">No score</div>
```

hide that div (in pure CSS) when inner Text is "No score"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as i'm concerned you can't select the inner text of an html tag.

What you can do is using html data-attributes

```
<div data-score="No score"></div>
```

And then

```
[data-score="No score"] {
    color:red;
}
```

One css function that can interest you is the [attr](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr) function.